# Sorting elements into equal groups

Tags: combinatorics

While studying combinatorics, I came across a problem which said:
If 3n different things can be equally distributed among 3 persons in k ways, then the number of ways to divide the 3n things in 3 equal groups is?
The answer was $\frac{k}{3!}$. 
 Why are we dividing by $3!$ here?
According to me, $$k=\binom {3n}{n}.\binom{2n}{n}$$ I have not permutated their positions because it's the distribution that matters, not the arrangement. So I think the answer should be k, for the groups as well. What is so different between boxes and humans? 
 (I saw a post somewhat similar to this. It only proves the formula, and does not answer my question. This is not a duplicate.)

Comment: Are your three groups *labeled*?  If they are labeled, then your answer is correct.  If they are not labeled, then the book's answer is correct.  If we had the three elements $\{a,b,c\}$ note the difference between having one unlabeled partition of this: $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ and having six labeled partitions of this: $(\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}),(\{a\},\{c\},\{b\}),(\{b\},\{a\},\{c\}),\dots$

Comment: "*What's so different between boxes and humans*"  Boxes can be without a label and can be treated as otherwise identical and the same.  Humans, typically, will have different names, different hopes and dreams, different hairstyles, etc... and will almost always be treated as distinct in problems such as these.

Comment: @JMoratviz but I did not encounter any such problems in, say, 'The number of words of four letters containing equal number of vowels and consonants (repetition allowed) is?' Are the groups of the 4 letter words labelled here? Shouldn't we multiplying the answer by $\frac{4!}{m!}$, where m depends on the number of letters repeated in different cases(m=1 for all different letters etc.)?

Comment: You can tell the difference between "AABB" and "ABAB" as well as "BBAA" in your words example.  It is not that the "*groups of the 4 letter words*" are labeled... there is no such "group" to talk about.  The **positions** of each letter within said words however *are* labeled.  The letter in the first position of "AABB" for instance is A and there is no ambiguity about that.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I got it. As a final confirmation: ifI were to form 4 teams of three people each, then we  _would_ divide it by (4!) since surely the ordering of teams does not matter in this case?

Comment: That depends on if the teams are labeled or unlabeled.  In some cases you will, in other cases you won't.  If you care about the first team being "the first team" rather than the second team, then you do not.  If all you cared about was who were teamed up with who but don't care their team name you do.

Comment: @JMoratviz got it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, the value of k doesn’t really matter to know why 3! shows up here.
You can simply work backwards to say since number of ways to divide the 3n objects in three groups is k/3!.Number of ways to distribute these groups among 3 people must be 3!.(k/3!) =k